# Axis 2 generated code in "Expanded Mode"

Tags: java, jboss, apache-axis

I'm having some problems understanding how to send a request to a web service that I have deployed. I have followed the following tutorial:
http://wso2.org/library/1719

Which I have successfully applied, and it worked well. The tutorial was straightforward, and I have easily generated a web service client. All I did was creating "request" objects from the exposed web service method, set its arguments, and then using the web service stub, I have passed the request object to the exposed web service method, and got a response.

Now, I have received a WSDL file from which I'm supposed to build a web service client as well. The problem is that the generated files from the WSDL differ greatly from that of the tutorial I followed. I learned later on that when generating clients using ADB, there is a mode called "Expanded Mode" that generates " a class for each of the outer elements and the named complex types " (http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/adb/adb-howto.html#gen_modes). The problem is that I'm unable to understand how to create a request object and get a response from the web service from the generated classes. My best shot was as follows:

```
GetMfrInventoryProductItemsListE wrapper = new GetMfrInventoryProductItemsListE();
GetMfrInventoryProductItemsList request = new GetMfrInventoryProductItemsList();
request.setArg0(deviceId);
request.setArg1(macAddresses);
request.setArg2(mfrKey);
wrapper.setGetMfrInventoryProductItemsList(request);
GetMfrInventoryProductItemsListResponseE wrapperResponse = wmService.getMfrInventoryProductItemsList(wrapper);
GetMfrInventoryProductItemsListResponse response = wrapperResponse.getGetMfrInventoryProductItemsListResponse();
return response.get_return();
```

In the above code *getGetMfrInventoryProductItemsList* is the name of my exposed web service method, and *wmService* is my stub.

The result was the following stack Trace :

```
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at wavemark.wmservice.soap.WMServiceStub.getMfrInventoryProductItemsList(WMServiceStub.java:3275)
    at wavemark.linkserver.supplierconnect.controller.WsStub.getMfrInventoryProductItemsList(WsStub.java:107)
    at wavemark.linkserver.supplierconnect.controller.WsManager.getProductItems(WsManager.java:384)
    at wavemark.linkserver.supplierconnect.webservices.SupplierConnect.getProductItems(SupplierConnect.java:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    ... 42 more
```

After trying to debug the problem, I have found out that this is the line that is throwing the exception:

```
GetMfrInventoryProductItemsListResponseE wrapperResponse = wmService.getMfrInventoryProductItemsList(wrapper);
```

I just want you guys to tell me if the way I'm using the request/response objects is correct.Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"..stack Trace .. truncated.."*  Was there a 'caused by' part to the trace?

Comment: I have included the rest of the stack trace in my post. I hope this would make things easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to solve the problem. Apparently the web service call that I was making, was taking a lot of time that it was timing out as the stack trace shows. So I added the following to my code to the section where I was instantiating my client stub:

```
            wmService = new WMServiceStub();

            Options options = new Options();
            EndpointReference epr = new EndpointReference(url);
            options.setTo(epr); 
            options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(300000));             

            wmService._getServiceClient().setOptions(options);
```

This results in increasing the Axis 2 web services' socket timeout to 5 minutes, which should be more than enough to most web service calls. I hope that this will be helpful for some developers out there.